# How to clear (or undraw) canvas using Mouse Coordinates only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm using React to draw on a canvas with the client's Mouse Coordinates.

However I'm trying to clear an existing canvas using the client's Mouse Coordinates as well. How could I do that? Basically the canvas will only be cleared in the mouseover zones.

Finally is there a way to add style attributes to this path using `context`?

Comment: So you want to achieve something along the lines of the eraser tool in Paint? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of something that may help you.

```html
<body id="paper" onload="init()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #000" onmousedown="deleting=true" onmouseup="deleting=false"></canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var body = document.getElementById("paper");
    var deleting = false;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop; //this updates the mouse coordinates
        });

        if (typeof mousemove != "undefined") {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //red rect filling the canvas
    }
    
    function update() {
        if (deleting) {
            ctx.clearRect(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10); //10 is our "brush size", you can change that.
        }
    }
    
    update();
    setInterval(update, 10); //JavaScript must keep checking if you're deleting anything. You can decrease the interval for more frequent updating.
    draw();
</script>
```

If you're working an app about drawing, this should give you an idea of how to make it.

`ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);` is how drawing could work.